# Do hornets remember and recognize a human? Do they have any (kind of) memory?

Tags: behaviour, memory, invertebrates

## hornetology

So it happens that a hornet (*vespa crabro*) flew inside my house today and now is being held in a plastic container (I made some holes to let it breathe). But it also happens not just this once, but twice and I guess it's not over (we live by a small forest, probably it builds its own nest there). I wonder if hornets may have some memory - can it  remember and later recognize a human?
And if I take it to another place of the town I live in and let it go there will 'he' come back, 'cause it will remember where 'he' lived before?

Thanks for any advice, I just don't want to simply kill it... 'him'.

Comment: As far as I know, many vespids have very good orientation, which is used to find food. If they find something with sugar like ripe fallen apples, they will start by scouting and mapping the area, and then they can fly back to base and to the food area again. so, they recognize their home and food places very well. to disorient them, I 'd figure you can test it out... mark him and take him a mile away, i think it would be enough, 10 would more probably be ok.

Comment: There is strong evidence that wasps can recognize color patterns of other wasps. Whether that extends to humans I don't think is known but given some remarkable work on bee learning, I would not be surprised. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rx7lEBE-wJE

Answer (score 2):

Most studies show that a hornet will give off a hormone that tells others in its hive that you or someone else is target and threat to the colony as a whole. They also are able to remember their surroundings near the hive or nest fairly well.

Comment: The aforementioned studies should be linked in the answer.

Comment: @G.Shepherd, do you have articles on this? I tried to google it but without success :(